# Segmentation fault while using argv[]

Tags: c

I keep running into a "Segmentation Fault" while trying to enter less than 5 parameters into the program. I know Java, but am new to C, and I'm just not sure what is going on. I'm just simply trying to convert user entered kg (as a parameter) to the number of Prius' in weight it would be, to the decimal.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) //Argc is the argument count, argv is the argument vector
{

    //Initialize the toyota/user variables  
    int toyota = 1325; //Toyota weight in kg
    int paramOne = atoi(argv[1]);
    int paramTwo = atoi(argv[2]);
    int paramThree = atoi(argv[3]);
    int paramFour = atoi(argv[4]);

    //This if will check to see if there are too many parameters    
    if (argc >= 5)
    {
        printf("Error: Too many parameters.\n");
        printf("Usage: ./HW1 arg1 [arg2 ... arg4].\n");
    }

    //This if will check to see if there are too few parameters
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Error: Too few parameters.\n");
        printf("Usage: ./HW1 arg1 [arg2 ... arg4.\n");
    }


    //If there are a correct amount of parameters, this will print the TP count
    if ((argc >= 1) && (argc <= 4))
    {
        printf("%d number of parameters.\n", argc);     

        if(argc >= 1)
        {

            printf("%d kg = %d TP.\n", paramOne, paramOne/toyota); //Parameter divided by TP
        }

        if(argc >= 2)
        {
            printf("%d kg = %d TP.\n", paramTwo, paramTwo/toyota);  
        }

        if(argc >= 3)
        {
            printf("%d kg = %d TP.\n", paramThree, paramThree/toyota);  
        }

        if(argc >= 4)
        {
            printf("%d kg = %d TP.\n", paramFour, paramFour/toyota);    
        }




    }

}
```

Comment: What should this program do? Why the need for some many parameters?

Comment: If you input less than 5 arguments, why do you expect not to get a segfault? `argv[4]` will be out-of-bounds, and possibly the others will, too.

Comment: Delay calling atoi until you've tested argc.

Comment: Please don't capitalize C identifiers. C is case-sensitive. Your title (before I edited it) referred to `Argv`, which is a completely different identifier from `argv`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int paramOne = atoi(argv[1]);
int paramTwo = atoi(argv[2]);
int paramThree = atoi(argv[3]);
int paramFour = atoi(argv[4]);
```

If `argc <= 4` these calls invoke undefined behavior. Test `argc` before and don't call `atoi` if there are not enough arguments.

Comment: You mean if `argc < 1`

Comment: @ouah Thank you a lot, I'm not quite sure why I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1):

If someone inputs `./your_program param1 param2`, and your program calls `atoi(argv[3])`, then `atoi` gets handed an incorrect pointer. This is because the value inside `argv[3]` was never set (since your program was called only with two parameters). `atoi` is now trying to dereference the given garbage (because it *thinks* it's a legit pointer to a char), therefore causing a Segmention Fault.

Comment: Actually if the program was given two arguments, `argv[3]` will be `NULL`. Either way, the behaviour is still undefined.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach which has no upper bound:

```
int i = 1;
while (argv[i] != NULL)
{
    int param = atoi(argv[i]);
    printf("%d kg = %d TP.\n", param, param/toyota);
    i++;
}
```